# Are there Application Variables in Vertx?

Tags: java, microservices, vert.x

I am looking to set custom objects in Application scope variables so that vertx has access to it across all micro-service requests. I couldn't find anything in Vertx documentation. In Java EE Servlet the code for similar feature is

```
getServletContext().getAttribute("application_data")
getServletContext().setAttribute("application_data", data);
```

Comment: Where/how do you want to use the value?

Comment: I check apipermissions before calling any route with the code below. Due to an issue with OAuth2 logout/revoke, I need to keep a map of accesstoken->refreshtoken which I want to keep and read from in memory rather than storing in the db.

  
  apiRouter.post("/api/v1/*").handler(AuthHandlers::checkAPIPermissions);

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For global data, you should simply use shared data. This has the additional benefit of being accessible across the cluster.

The following code uses a *local* map:

```
SharedData sd = vertx.sharedData();
LocalMap<String, String> map1 = sd.getLocalMap("mymap1");
map1.put("foo", "bar");
```

Reading is similarly easy:

```
String val = map1.get("foo");
```

The documentation is [on this page](https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-core/java/#_using_shared_data_with_vert_x)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Would you rather go with Asynchronous shared maps in the scenario, in case the application is scaled to several nodes?

Comment: Ultimately, yes, I would. But if this is a single-server application, this should be just fine.